# Capturar un error de conversión en wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

hace poco empecé a trabajar con wpf y mvvm y me he topado con un problema que no logro resolver aún.

En mi ViewModel tengo un `Nullable<decimal>` bindeado con una vista en xaml.

```
public class Ejemplo: BaseViewModel<Ejemplo>
{
    public decimal? Test {get; set;}
}
```

Y lo bindeo en xaml de la siguiente manera:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Lo que funciona sin ningún problema.

El asunto es, que al momento de introducir un valor no válido, la validación en xaml se produce automáticamente (por ejemplo, escribiendo una letra).

Lo que pretendo, es poder reaccionar a este error dentro de mi `ViewModel`, para así poder modificar otras propiedades cuando el valor de `Test` es erróneo (como por ejemplo deshabilitar un botón..)

Intenté hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
private decimal? mTest;
public decimal? Test 
{
    get => mTest;
    set 
    {
        try
        { 
            mTest = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(m => m.Test);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Realizo la limpieza de la que hablo..
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero, para mi sorpresa, el Setter de `Test` nunca se ejecuta.

¿Cómo debería hacer para reaccionar ante esto?

Comment: Que estas usando para validar? porque en base a eso tu boton podria estar conectado a una variable que le diga si el modelo es valido o no

Comment: @gbianchi absolutamente nada, es la validación por defecto del wpf

Comment: No hay validacion por defecto.. por eso pregunto. al modelo no va a ir nada, porque el casteo falla antes de llegar. en tu propiedad, value es del mismo tipo que la propiedad, por lo tanto poner una letra implica que no va a llegar nada, porque falla al tratar de generar el value.

Comment: @gbianchi literalmente el bindeo que hice es directo, existe el ViewModel y el archivo xaml, sin ningún converter ni otro intermediaro, por eso asumo que el mismo wpf tiene algun método para manejarlo que pueda sobreescribir

Comment: Esta solo validando los tipos. No esta validando datos en si. Ahora, tranquilamente vos podrias tener una propiedad en tu viewmodel conectada a un boton, donde si todos los campos son correctos esta en true, y en caso de error esta en false.

Comment: @gbianchi el tema del botón lo tengo manejado con el `CanExecute` de `ICommand`, el tema es que para forzar que vuelva a evaluarse debería acceder al Setter para disparar el evento `CanExecuteChanged` o no?

Comment: Ah me mataste.. nunca me gustaron los ICommand, pase olimpicamente de ellos pq solo sirven para los botones.

Comment: @gbianchi mi idea es activar un botón y modificar un `TextBlock` para mostrar que hay algo que está mal, sabes si existe alguna manera de detectar que los tipos no coinciden para efectivamente editar el `TextBlock`? me explico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para sobrescribir la conversión por defecto que realiza wpf, debes implementar IvalueConverter:
En tu XML deberías tener algo así:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <my:DecimalConverter x:Key="DecimalConverter"></my:DecimalConverter>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Test, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource DecimalConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

E implementar IValueConverter:

```
class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ///Tu código iría aquí
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ///Tu código iría aquí          
        }
    }
```

Con lo que podrás controlar la conversión por defecto a la que haces referencia, pero por otro lado, para habilitar o deshabilitar botones, suelo implementar `INotifyDataErrorInfo` y enlazar la propiedad IsEnabled de los botones al `HasError`. En el XAML del control debes tener  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, y realizar la implementación de la interface en el código (yo suelo implementarla en una clase base para el viewModel)